# Find center of ellipse provided coordinates of one focus, and point on ellipse with it's tangent

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

> At a point $A(1,1)$ on ellipse, equation of tangent is $y=x$. If one of the foci of ellipse is $(0,-2)$ and the coordinates of centre of ellipse are $(\alpha,\beta)$ then find the value of $\alpha+\beta$. It is given that the length of major axis of the ellipse is $4\sqrt{10}$ units.

**Solution given**

Let $S(0,-2)$ and $S'$ be foci of ellipse. Then the slope of $AS'=\frac13$ and $AS'=3\sqrt{10}$

So the coordinates of $S'$ will be $(10,4)$ and centre is mid point of $S$ and $S'$.

---

I understand why the slope of $AS'$ is $\frac13$ but I cannot understand why $AS'$ has to be $3\sqrt{10}$. If I can prove former, I can easily calculate the coordinates of $S'$.

Please help me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles. The current one tells us absolutely nothing about the question.

Comment: @Shaun can you help me...I'm stuck on this problem for over half an hour

Comment: I don't know how, sorry. Your new title isn't much better.

Comment: The distance from the focus to a point on the ellipse to the other focus is constant and equal to the length of the major axis.

Comment: I have edited the title to be more descriptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that for all points on the ellipse, the sum of the two distances to the foci is equal to the length of major axis.

So, we have $AS+AS'=4\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Thank you very much..I don't know how I forgot this property..once again thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Other focus is $(2\alpha, 2(\beta+1))$ since the center of the ellipse is the midpoint of the foci.

The sum of the distances to the foci is constant for an ellipse, twice the semi-major axis$=4\sqrt{10}$ here.

Distance from $(1,1)$ to $(0,-2)$ is $\sqrt{10}$ which means $(2\alpha, 2(\beta+1))$ is $3\sqrt{10}$ from $(1,1)$.

So : $(2\alpha -1)^2+(2\beta+1)^2=90$

Law of reflection:

$<1,3>/\sqrt{10}\cdot <1,-1>/\sqrt{2}=-1/\sqrt{5}$

$<1-2\alpha, -2\beta-1>/3\sqrt{10} \cdot <1,-1>/\sqrt{2}=1/\sqrt{5}$

$(1-2\alpha+2\beta+1)=6\implies \beta=\alpha+2$

$(2\alpha-1)^2+(2\alpha+5)^2=90$

$4\alpha^2-4\alpha+1+4\alpha^2+20\alpha+25=90$

$8\alpha^2+16\alpha-64=0$

$\alpha^2+2\alpha+1=9\implies \alpha \in\{2,-4 \}\implies \beta \in \{4,-2\}$

$|\alpha+\beta|=6$